# Elementary Linear Algebra Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

*Image of question:*

[image]

*End image of question.*

---

Having a little a trouble with this one just some review I was doing on proofs, haven't done them in a while.

Comment: multiply your matrix and an arbitrary matrix in both orders and solve a system of linear equations

Comment: hint: eigenvalues of P are 2 and 3 then  what are the eigenvectors of P?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\left[ \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix}\right]$. Then compute $AP$ and $PA$.

We get

$AP=PA \iff 2a+c=2a, 2b+d=a+3b, 3c=2c$ and $3d+c=3d$.

It is now easy to see that

$AP=PA \iff c=0$ and $d=a+b$.